# Laravel Resource - Access to User

Tags: laravel

I have an API built using Passport, Laravel 5.5.

Uses Password Grant system.

I have routes called /api/company/get/{id} and /api/company/search which will return CompanyResource object(s). These routes are not requiring a logged in user

Inside the CompanyResource I am being passed the $request. Inside the resource, I need to manipulate how data is returned based on the logged in user **IF they exist** ... if Auth::user()->is_special

so when i make a call to the /api/company/get/{id} , with an access token Bearer ... 
will this set the Auth object for me to use it??? Laravel documentation show the Auth being accessed https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

When creating an access token (passing credentials) and making an api with it or without it - i want to see / access the logged in User if its exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best practise, but we implemented a custom middleware called auth.optional that extends regular auth.api middleware. It basicly allows the request to actual endpoint rather than throwing a AuthException, when the token is not valid or present.

Because regular api middleware do not allow if the request has no token, thus it is not useful for auth-free endpoints.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;

class OptionalAuthenticate extends Authenticate {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {
        try {
            $this->authenticate(array('api'));
        } catch(AuthenticationException $e) {
            //Do nothing
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Check Authenticate class that we are extending to see where it throws an AuthenticationException.

Comment: I want my route which doesnt have auth.api on it to be able to get the user passed in to the route via token... this will not stop the user/requestor from getting the data back but they may just get more if they are a authed user

Comment: i offered a solution exactly for this. extend the middleware and comment out the line that throws the exception. you are able to do this by overriding the function.

Comment: questions : 1) will the Auth user() be available? 2) do i have to add this auth:optional in my route api for this route?  3) can you provide an example of extended the middleware?

Comment: 3) can you provide an example of extended the api:auth middleware, i dont know how to handle this? 4) this cannot effect my web auth processes

Comment: here is my config/auth as this uses passport :   'guards' => [ 'web' => [ 'driver' => 'session', 'provider' => 'users', ], ''' 'api' => [ 'driver' => 'passport', 'provider' => 'users', ], ],

Comment: 1) Yes.
2) You can add your custom middleware to global middlewares, so you don't have to explicitly add the middleware to a specific route, or you can simply add the middleware to routes that you want to pass through middleware. We are using the latter right now.
3) I updated my answer for example code.

Note: You don't need to change any config file. You just need to register your new middleware via Middleware/Kernel.php. Recaching of configs may be needed.